# Maven dependency cache not working on Gitlab Runner

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have spent an ample lot of time on this, and it doesn't seem to work. Have tried on multiple projects.

We host our gitlab runner ourselves (on our AWS via EKS) managed by Gitlab (SaaS). I want it to cache the maven dependencies.

When I configure it based on the reference example: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-yml/blob/master/Maven.gitlab-ci.yml , it still downloads all the dependencies every time.

```
stages:
  - test
  - pack

image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"


cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository


stylecheck_and_test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - tags
    - schedulers
    - web
    - triggers
    - branches
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean test
```

Comment: Do you want caching between jobs / pipelines / branches / projects?

Comment: Anything. I just want to make it work. Branches is fine

Comment: This Gitlab-Doc (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) could help you.

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: can you please post logs of your job, ideally you should see below logs when caching works fine

`Checking cache for default...

Downloading cache.zip from https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/****/default 

Successfully extracted cache
....
....
....
....

Creating cache default...
.m2/repository: found 2251 matching files and directories 

Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/gitlab-com-runners-cache/project/****/default 

Created cache
`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just faile the ci script so the cache  was not created.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like local repo and cache paths are mismatch, Try with this.

```
stages:
  - test
  - pack

image: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8    

variables:
      MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dmaven.repo.local=maven.repository -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
      MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"
    
    
    cache:
      paths:
        - maven.repository/

stylecheck_and_test:
  stage: test
  only:
    - tags
    - schedulers
    - web
    - triggers
    - branches
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean test
```